# Minecraft Forge 1.12.2 "No mod information found Ask your mod author to provide a mod mcmod.info file"

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm having some issues with loading my mod. It mostly works, however I can't figure out why my mcmod.info file isn't properly registering. I've looked at answers on here and other sites, however I still can't.

My mcmod.info file is :

```
[{
  "modid": "modexperimentation",
  "name": "Mod Experimentation",
  "description": "lorem ipsum",
  "version": "1.0",
  "mcversion": "1.12.2",
  "authorList": ["Lionmeow"],
  "credits": "None"
}]
```

My Main.java files has :

```java
@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION, useMetadata = true)
public class Main {

    @Mod.Instance
    public static Main instance;

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.COMMON_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @Mod.EventHandler
    public static void PreInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event){

    }

    @Mod.EventHandler
    public static void init(FMLInitializationEvent event){

    }

    @Mod.EventHandler
    public static void PostInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event){

    }

}
```

I'm not sure why, but it's stating that "No mod information found Ask your mod author to provide a mod mcmod.info file". It looks correctly formatted, so I have no clue.

Comment: Where is your mcmod.info file? In your source project, it should be in `src/main/resources/`. Is it there? Is it ending up in the jar? It should be in the root of the jar.

Comment: And is `Reference.MOD_ID` set to `modexperimentation`?

Comment: My mcmod.info file is indeed `src/main/resources/`. `Reference.MOD_ID` is set to modexperimentation as well.

Comment: In the built jar, do you see the mcmod.info in the root?

Comment: It looks like it's in the root of the jar, yes.